# Is it possible to boot directly into ubuntu without going to the interface of grub options?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

My computer is installed with ubuntu 16.04 and windows 7 dual system, however I seldom use windows, so I found the grub options(selecting system) in booting is a bit less efficient.

Is it possible to set a default booting system without showing the interface (and of course it can be changed back if needed, e.g. by get into bios and change it)?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/403958/re-configure-grub-to-directly-boot-to-ubuntu-on-dual-boot?rq=1)

Comment: The grub menu timeout can be reduced -- to one second, for example. (But I'd prefer 2-3 seconds.) Look here: https://askubuntu.com/q/148095/300458