# How to remove the boot?

Tags: boot

I accidentally put it when give the command `sudo update-grub` and I just ignore the text and pressed 'y' and now I've a boot menu, but i dont wanna this. I've only an OS.

I'm trying to learn about linux, so if you could explain it will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: /etc/default/grub is empty.

Comment: So what? You can still add settings to it, can't you? Also see: http://askubuntu.com/a/157940/158442

Comment: I don't know why, but my update-grub doesn't work, seems like it isn't installed.

Comment: You get a command-not-found error?

Comment: Yes. `sudo: update-grub: command not found`

Comment: What happens if you do `sudo apt-get install grub-pc`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28932/discussion-between-jluann-and-muru).

Answer (score 0):

## How To disable the boot options

1. Open terminal and type    `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Here the grub file will open in that file change the GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false change to GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
3. Save the file
4. Now update grub using

   `sudo apt-get update`

> Note: Do not change anything else in the file.