# Ubuntu and Windows dualboot - Start Ubuntu without ask

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I've bought a new laptop, and I'd like to install ubuntu on it, but keep Windows also. I usually use only Ubuntu (even then I need to keep windows), so I'd like to get my laptop starting on Ubuntu without asking to select a O.S.

My laptop has a SSD so I want to feel all fast as it can be, not askin on start up. Also I'd like to be able to change this set up and be able to choose Windows if it's needed. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an answer here:

> [How to remove or hide the GRUB boot menu? 2 answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18775/how-to-remove-or-hide-the-grub-boot-menu)
>
> [How do I skip the Grub menu on a dual-boot system? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157925/how-do-i-skip-the-grub-menu-on-a-dual-boot-system)