# How do I delete one Ubuntu from several Ubuntu's but keep its grub and boot loader?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I am in trouble with my computer.

I installed Windows10 at first.

I then installed Ubuntu 18 and the grub occurred every time I boot my computer.

Later, I installed Ubuntu 16. The grub of Ubuntu 16 seemed to replace the grub of Ubuntu 18.

Now, I want to delete the Ubuntu 16, but I want to keep the Ubuntu 18.

Should I delete the "/boot" partition? Should I keep the "/boot/efi" or "/boot/grub" partition?

And what is the recommended size for "/boot" and "/boot/efi" in Ubuntu 20 if I try installing it later? Will the Ubuntu 20 move the kernels from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Most desktops do not need a /boot partition. And that cannot be shared with other distributions with potential conflicts. The ESP - efi system partition is shared, but only one /EFI/ubuntu folder will exist and it normally the last install or last major update to grub. You can boot newest install & reinstall grub or manually edit /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg in ESP. https://askubuntu.com/questions/792413/how-to-set-grub-from-second-linux-distribution-as-default-in-uefi-boot

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist *snap* based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18, so do you mean Ubuntu Core 18? Ubuntu Core 16? & Ubuntu Core 20?