# Install two Ubuntu 20.04 on the same disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, system-installation, ssd

I would like to install a second Ubuntu on my PC, for security reasons (separating my private stuff from experimental software and games, etc).

I only have only one SSD and would like to install a completely independent second Ubuntu 20.04 next to my existing one. Can I just install a second Ubuntu (with an installation stick) onto a new partition on my SSD? Or are there special things I have to change/ problems I will encounter?

Comment: Create another partition. Choose `Something Else` during installation and install there.

Comment: Why would you need a 2nd Ubuntu for that? Create another user, Create a partition,set it to be owned by that user and the other user can not reach it. We take security serious... a user is the only thing you need to separate your documents. IF there is a security breach a 2nd Ubuntu is -not- going to save you.

Comment: You can create a second Ubuntu from scratch as Archisman Panigrahi  suggests or you can clone your current OS partition using copy-paste in GParted. If you choose clone you will need to change the new partition's UUID also using GParted. Confirm UUID is grub.cfg and fstab.

Comment: Last install will be grub that is in control. And if major update to grub each install may update boot order. You have to manage which grub is in control. If UEFI, it is /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file's UUID that find full grub.cfg in your install. Or install without grub (ubiquity -b) and use main working install's grub by updating it to find new install. I prefer separate install, as you may install apps you do not want or want to test before adding to main working install. See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/792413/how-to-set-grub-from-second-linux-distribution-as-default-in-uefi-boot

Comment: @Rinzwind two Ubuntu installations may make sense if someone wants to try installing and uninstalling different things, especially ones that heavily modify the system (like eg. WINE) while keeping the "main" installation as "clean" as possible and installing only necessary things there - ie. one instalnce is for work and the other one for experimenting...

Answer (score 1):

Make an unallocated partition on your SSD using [gparted](https://gparted.org/) and choose

```
something else
```

while installing your new ubuntu and install your new ubuntu on that unallocated space.

Hope it will work..!