# Grub2 on USB with Xubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, xubuntu

I recently installed Xubuntu 16.04.1 (x86) on my 64 GB USB flashdrive.  I installed it using the installation DVD I burned.

My USB has 3 partitions (in this order):
**1**.  12 GB data storage for use on windows computers,
**2**.  main install/root EXT4 partition,
**3**.  and 2 GB swap area

**NOTE:** GRUB2 is installed on the correct device.  Xubuntu is fully installed, not an installation ISO image.

Everything is working fine, but there is one major annoyance/potential problem: on the GRUB2 menu, it includes the option to load Windows Vista from the computer I used to do the installation.

- How do I remove this option from the GRUB2 menu?
- Also, is it possible that on some computers I might boot my USB from,
  GRUB2 might not be able to load Xubuntu (EX: on a computer w/o a hard
  drive, or with other USB drives plugged in)?

Comment: You can turn off os-prober, so it does not search for other installs. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/704642/skip-grub-at-boot/704728#704728 And or you can totally edit grub yourself. I like to add ISO for various repair systems and use grub to boot those. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen and: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus

Comment: @oldfred  Thanks!  Turning off os-prober solved the problem.