# Removing boot options

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive

I want to skip the GRUB loading screen or remove any other option besides Ubuntu.

I've installed another Linux distro on my other internal harddrive; however, I only want to be able to boot the other distro if I change boot-priority in the BIOS.

I did install GRUB on both harddrives.

I've tried editing `/etc/default/grub` with

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

but it did not work, nor is it exactly what I want.

Comment: I do not suggest 0 on normal timeout, as then you may not be able to get to grub menu if needed. I use 3 sec.  Duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/704642/skip-grub-at-boot/704728#704728

Comment: But isn't that just the setting for my primary harddrive. Shouldn't I be able to use grub from the other harddrive :)?

Comment: As long as it is configured to get into grub menu, that should work. But if you configure all grubs to not use menu, and have system issue, you may only be able to use your Ubuntu live installer in live mode as repair disk.