# ubuntu grub update breaks antergos

Tags: grub2

I have a multi-boot system with Windows 10, Ubuntu 18.04 and Antergos installed.
Every time Ubuntu update grub, it breaks my Antergos boot, Antergos starts to boot and fails with a kernel panic.

I usually solve the issue by repairing grub from an Antergos live CD, then I can boot again the three systems until Ubuntu pushes a new kernel version.

As I am growing tired of this, I am looking for a better solution.
I think there is something wrong in grub automatic configuration script in Ubuntu, but I cannot make any sense out of it.
Can anyone point me to where/what to look for?

Comment: Do not know Antergos, Wwhen you update boot from its CD, are you converting to using it as default boot? Can you then add correct boot stanza into 40_custom. I would also add the Windows boot and turn off os-prober. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the summary report ( not post full report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & https://askubuntu.com/questions/848119/how-to-update-grub-on-a-dual-boot-machine/848614#848614

Comment: Antergos is just Arch linux comming with an installer/live CD.

Comment: When I repair grub, I do not use Boot-Repair tool: I just mount all the partitions from my arch filesystem, chroot to it (using arch-chroot script) and run grub-mkconfig. This is sufficient to repair grub.  I am pretty sure this invoke os-prober from arch (antergos) environment. So the automatic multiboot detection works fine when done from arch but fail when done from ubuntu. At the moment it is working fine, until next ubuntu kernel update?...

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen  & this user uses Arch as default boot & created the link above. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205&page=54 (start on last page & go backward). Best then to turn off grub menu updates. If BIOS mode you can turn off updates in a file. Do not think that works with UEFI. I do this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/704642/skip-grub-at-boot/704728#704728, but grub will still update in Ubuntu.