# Why skipping Grub menu doesn't work?

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

I want to skip the Grub menu when starting my computer.
I edited the settings I found [*here*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157925/how-do-i-skip-the-grub-menu-on-a-dual-boot-system)

But it didn't work, which part of my settings is wrong?

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: After this do `sudo update-grub`

Comment: @Debian_yadav I did that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `0` to `0.0` and it works.

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0.0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.0
```

Comment: I think this might be a bug on Grub.

Answer (score 2):

According to `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'` you can also set

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

instead of the following, which are (or will be) deprecated:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

Don't forget to apply changes when you're done:

```
sudo update-grub
```